# Cannot reach timestamp server from within TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, signtool

Whenever I try to use `signtool.exe` with a timestamp server, running it from a build in TeamCity, it fails with the following error:

`EXEC The specified timestamp server either could not be reached or returned an invalid response.`

The signing is done from a .bat file containing the code below. The signing is fine, it's the timestamping that fails.

```
set SIGNTOOL_DIR=%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\

"%SIGNTOOL_DIR%signtool.exe" sign /f %1 /p mypassword /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /v %2
```

... and the batch file would be executed from Visual Studio with the following Post Build Event...

```
if $(ConfigurationName)==Release "$(SolutionDir)Sign.bat" "$(SolutionDir)myFile.pfx" "$(SolutionDir)obj\Release\myApplication.exe
```

The strange thing is it runs fine outside of Team City. If I build the solution which calls the above batch file in Visual Studio myself it completes fine every time.

Even when I remotely log into the server which runs TeamCity and execute the batch file from there (though I have to change `%ProgramFiles%` to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`) it runs no problem.

The results above are consistent so it's not just intermittent connection problems...

Comment: When you remotely log in on the TC agent, you have to change `%ProgramFiles%` to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`. When the TC agent runs it, why do you expect it to pass with plain `%ProgramFiles%`? (You're saying it works fine; I'm just curious.)

Comment: I am not sure, I am guessing that Visual Studio is smart enough to make that substitution, it does so on my own computer (which also requires the change if I run the batch file manually)... If I run from the command prompt without making the change, I get `The system cannot find the path specified` I assume refering to `signtool.exe`... Not the timestamp server error. If I echo `%programfiles%` and run in Visual Studio / TeamCity, then it displays `C:\Program Files (x86)` as if the change was automatically made or it changed the value of that variable. So I don't think that's the cause.